# Hotkey with simple colon ":" autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Why my script isn't working ?

```
<^>!:::
{
    MsgBox You pressed AltGr+:
    Return
}
```

Comment: I just saw that you solved it by using the scancode for [:].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of keyboard layout do you use? If I want to get to <kbd>:</kbd>, I have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>.

I can't use <kbd>RAlt</kbd> on my PC, but this works for me with the <kbd>LAlt</kbd> key:

```
!+`;:: ; Use + to shift the [;] key into [:] and use a back-tick [`] to literally interpret the next character.
{
    MsgBox You pressed [LAlt]+[:]
    Return
}
```